# Cache json in Trigger.IO

Tags: json, caching, trigger.io

Does anyone can help me with caching a json string in Trigger.io? I have a lot of json request for which i think its a good idea to cache them for say 1 hour for example. According to the jquery manual about $.ajax(Trigger.io points to this manual for forge.request.ajax) there is no caching for jsonp and script as a type but i'm using json here so i was hoping to do some caching on it.

I'm using the forge.request.ajax like so:

```
  forge.request.ajax({
    url: the_url_to_api,
    dataType: 'json',
    cache: true,
    success: function(data) {
      parsed_template = _.template( $('#sales_index_template').html(), {nowOnSale:     data.activeSales, soonOnSale: data.upcomingSales } );
      app.end_set_right_content(parsed_template);
    },
    error: function(error) {
    alert('Request for sales failed');
    }
  });
```

And this are my headers for the json return script in the API

- Date Tue, 28 Aug 2012 15:19:30 GMT
- x-powered-by PHP/5.3.15
- Connection Keep-Alive
- Content-Length 4294
- Pragma cache
- Server Apache/2.2.11 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.11 OpenSSL/0.9.8g PHP/5.3.15
- Content-Type application/json; charset=utf-8
- Cache-Control max-age=3600
- Keep-Alive timeout=5, max=100
- Expires Tue, 28 Aug 2012 16:19:30 GMT

With the above settings there is no caching going on if i look in chromes or safaris network debugger.. Maybe someone can help me with what i'm doing wrong? or maybe somebody has a better idea for caching in Trigger.io?

Thanks in advanche!

Comment: So you're running this as a browser extension at the moment? On Chrome and Safari, we just pass through request.ajax calls to jQuery, so you should be able to just get jQuery request caching working in isolation, then apply the same technique to request.ajax.

Comment: Ok so for web version its just jQuery.. on iOS / Android its a native http object then? in my network tool i only see a request to http://localhost:3000/_forge/proxy/moc/pivpohs/www/ which is always a POST and by the response time i know the result is not cached.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a recent application I developed I cache (in memory) the resulting json until the user presses the little "refresh" icon.  I guess I could add an extra user preference setting to automatically expire in x days.  Also, instead of using memory I could have utilized trigger.io to save the json to disk.

Here is the app if you want to see how I do it (Note: I committed a couple of untested tweeks this morning):

https://github.com/dragthor/south-ridge-app

The viewmanager.js handles most of the backbone.js model caching logic.  Basically I do the usual:

1. Is the model in the cache?
2. If Yes, then use cached model.
3. If No, then bind model (via json) add to cache.
4. Use it (the returned model).

Comment: Thanks for sharing your app! i was also thinking of a caching solution like this but i need to make a cache mechanism to force a new json request after a given timestamp. i thought just setting the headers on the api would be a better solution.

Comment: I accepted your answer. Your app has been useful for me and i go for a caching option like you have but then reset my cache object every 5 minutes like so: setInterval(function(){ cache = {}; }, 300000);